# GIF image issue with fbi linux tool

Tags: framebuffer

I am getting issue when I use `fbi` to display `gif` images. I see only first frame of `gif` image. It should be animate but it doesn't.

Command that I was using is:

```
sudo fbi -d /dev/fb0 -T 1 -noverbose -a Mystery-100x100.gif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry but I think fbi does not support animation, which is why it is only showing the first frame.

But the purpose of fbi is to show images in a terminal using framebuffer, then I guess any other solution which can do this would be good for you.

For example, here you can see a solution to see animated GIFs on framebuffer using just Qt programming:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=65346&p=945643

More precisely, I paste the procedure here, which assumes the file name is "load.gif".

1. Install QT binaries, in Ubuntu perhaps you may
   just need to run the following command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install qmlscene
   ```
2. Make a test.qml file:

   ```
   import QtQuick 2.0

    Rectangle {
       id: root
       width:800
       height:600
   color:"#000"
      AnimatedImage {
          id: viewerImage
          anchors.centerIn: parent
     source:"load.gif"
         fillMode:Image.PreserveAspectCrop
   }
    }
   ```
3. Run the following command:

   ```
   qmlscene -platform eglfs test.qml
   ```

I am not an expert of Qt, then I don't know how to pass any GIF filename as a command line argument (instead of "load.gif"), maybe some other Qt expert could help me improve the answer.

Otherwise you have the following very simple alternative: rename the GIF file to be animated by calling it load.gif (or make a copy of it), you can do this manually or in a bash script for example.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Please, include some relevant information here, as link may break in the future.